# Mongodb document with array of objects property: how match property of this array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is an image of what my user MongoDB document looks like. I have a skills array which contains objects with the follwing structure.

```
{
name: String,
points: Number,
skill: Schema.Types.ObjectId
}
```

**Here's a screenshot of an actual user document, you can see the skill with the name `html`**

[image]

Now I want to create a search query that would match the `name` property of one these objects in the skills array. e.g if my input is `htm` it would match with a user that has a skill with the name `html`. I tried it the way below, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone suggest me how to successfully do this?

```
const createSkillsQuery = (user, input) => User.find({
  $and: [
    { skills: { name: { $regex: input, $options: 'i' } } },
    { _workspace: user._workspace }
  ]
}).select('profile_pic full_name email created_date');
```

Comment: you don't need `$and` here. It's implicit.

Comment: Try `"skills.name": { $regex...`

Comment: Ok Sergio, I'll try it

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posted it as an answer, so I can earn some internet points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) here.

```
"skills.name": { $regex: input, $options: 'i' }
```